# Check receipt if there is five or more of a product

Tags: c#

I have a basic object SalesLine, which contains the property quantity. I need to know if any of the SalesLine object has a quantity of five or more. In a simple world, you could just check if the SalesLine object has 5 or more of quantity:

```
foreach(SalesLine salesline in Transaction.SalesLines
   {
     if(salesline.Quantity >=5)
   }
```

but unfortunately we do not live in one. If a cashier scans 4 of product a, then scans product b, then scans one more of product a, it won't be summarized on one line. We now have three salesline in Transaction.SalesLines, but only two unique products. To know which SalesLine are of the same product, we can use the property SalesLine.ItemID.

How would one write a code which basically checks if there exists five or more of any of the unique products?

Comment: can you please post your SalesLine class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If a cashier scans 4 of product a, then scans product b, then scans one more of product a, it won't be summarized on one line

Then fix that when scanning an item and adding it to your collection? It makes the entire process easier, including printing a receipt.

Alternatively, group all lines by a unique identifier for the product, so something like:

```
foreach (var products in Transaction.SalesLines.GroupBy(s => s.EAN))
{
    int productQuantity = products.Sum(p => p.Quantity);
}
```

Comment: That would of course be the best way, but the receipt is a proof of how the cashier scanned the products. That's why they don't summarize the SalesLine by the unique itemid.

Comment: the quantity is actually a decimal, but I guess I can just do (int)p.Quantity. Great answer, exactly what I was thinking.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. This will summarize quantity by itemid

```
foreach (var item in list.GroupBy(x => x.ItemID).Where(x => x.Sum(i=>i.Quantity) >= 5))
{
    /*your stuff*/
}
```